# TCL regexp pattern search

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to find a pattern match as below
`abc(xxxx):efg(xxxx):xyz(xxxx)` where `xxxx` - [0-9] digits

I used

```
set string "my string is abc(xxxx):efg(xxxx):xyz(xxxx)"
regexp abc(....):efg(....):xyz(....) $string result_str
```

it returns 0. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you've got is that `(` and `)` have special meaning to regular expressions in Tcl (and many other RE engines besides) in that they denote a capturing sub-RE. To make the characters “normal”, they have to be escaped with a backslash, and that means that it's best to put the regular expression in braces (because backslashes are general Tcl metacharacters).

Thus:

```
% set string "my string is abc(xxxx):efg(xxxx):xyz(xxxx)"
% regexp {abc\(....\):efg\(....\):xyz\(....\)} $string
1
```

If you want to *also* capture the contents of those parentheses, you need a slightly more complex RE:

```
regexp {abc\((....)\):efg\((....)\):xyz\((....)\)} $string \
        all abc_bit efg_bit xyz_bit
```

Note that those `....` sequences always match exactly four characters, but it's better to be more specific. To match any number of digits in each case:

```
regexp {abc\((\d+)\):efg\((\d+)\):xyz\((\d+)\)} $string -> abc efg xyz
```

<sup>When using `regexp` to extract bits of a string, it's pretty common to use `->` as a (rather strange) variable name for the whole string match; it looks mnemonically like it's saying “send the pieces extracted to these variables”.</sup>

Comment: And when testing interactively, `regexp -inline` is great as it returns a list of all the matched substrings instead of whether a match was found.

Comment: thanks Donal and others for valuable suggestion.Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not worked with tcl but seems like you need to escape the `(` and `)`. Also if you are sure that the `x`'s would be digits, use `\d{4}` instead of `....`. Based on this, the updated regex you could try is

`abc\(\d{4}\):efg\(\d{4}\):xyz\(\d{4}\)`.

Comment: this fails. When I try with string abc(12):efg(78) regexp abc(..):efg(..) it works. Not sure what's causing the issue with four digits.

Comment: sorry, i thought that the `xxxx` in your question meant exactly 4 digits. If it can be any number of digits then replace `\d{4}` with `\d+` in the regex.

Comment: also based on the example in your comment it seems that `abc(xxx)` can be repeated any number of times (in your question you used `abc...efg...xyz...`). Can you please clarify so i can update the answer if required?

Comment: it's four digits only. I used abc(.+):efg(.+):xyz(.+). it worked.. but not sure if this is the safe method to use.