# Replace \tag{contents} with its contents using TCL (multiple instances)

Tags: tcl

The problem: there is a string with tags (in LaTeX), and I need to replace **\textbf{*contents*}** with just **contents** using TCL and regexps only (I have TCL v8.4). The tag occurs multiple times in a string.

So, here is what I have:

> The use of **\textbf{cosine}** rather than **\textbf{sine}** functions is critical for compression, since it turns out that **\textbf{fewer cosine functions are needed to approximate a typical signal}**.

Here is what I want:

> The use of **cosine** rather than **sine** functions is critical for compression, since it turns out that **fewer cosine functions are needed to approximate a typical signal**.

I understand that [I have to escape the special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983690/tcl-regexp-pattern-search?rq=1) in **regsub**, but I cannot find how to do this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
set project_contents {The use of \textbf{cosine} rather than \textbf{sine} functions is critical for compression, since it turns out that \textbf{fewer cosine functions are needed to approximate a typical signal}.}

set match [ regexp -all -inline  {\\textbf\x7B([^\x7D]*)\x7D} $project_contents ]
foreach {trash needed_stuff} $match {

regsub -- {\\textbf\{$trash\}} $project_contents   $needed_stuff    project_contents
}
```

that finds the tagged text (in $trash) and the text without tags (in $needed_stuff),  but does not replace them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key things you are looking for are that the RE needs to be in `{`braces`}`, and the literal backslash and braces in the RE need to be backslash-quoted. You also want to use a non-greedy quantifier in there and the `-all` option to `regsub`:

```
set project_contents {The use of \textbf{cosine} rather than \textbf{sine} functions is critical for compression, since it turns out that \textbf{fewer cosine functions are needed to approximate a typical signal}.}
set plain_text_contents [regsub -all {\\textbf\{(.*?)\}} $project_contents {\1}]
puts $plain_text_contents
```

This produces this output:

```
The use of cosine rather than sine functions is critical for compression, since it turns out that fewer cosine functions are needed to approximate a typical signal.
```

Which looks like the sort of thing you desire.